# Spring No matching bean of type ... found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I have trouble with matching bean. My project is based on the project from "Spring in action"

```
No matching bean of type [com.kmazur.data.BoardRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'boardController' defined in file [C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MVCWebApi\WEB-INF\classes\com\kmazur\web\BoardController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.kmazur.data.BoardRepository]: : No matching bean of type [com.kmazur.data.BoardRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.kmazur.data.BoardRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

And servlet-context.xml

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>



<context:component-scan base-package="com.kmazur.*" />
```

web.xml

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Classes

```
public interface BoardRepository {

List<Board> findUsers(long max, int count);

Board findOne(long boardId);
}
```

And

```
public class Board {
private final Long id;
private final String message;
private final Date time;
private Double latitude;
private Double longitude;
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/boards")
public class BoardController {

private static final String MAX_LONG_AS_STRING = "9223372036854775807";


private BoardRepository boardRepository;


@Autowired
public BoardController(BoardRepository boardRepository) {
    this.boardRepository = boardRepository;
}
```

I have already tried adding adnotation in different ways, but the error was always the same.

Comment: Where is your concrete implementation of BoardRepository? And if you have one, does it have spring annotation on it (like @Component or @Repository)?

Comment: I am trying to make it like in the book,which do not make any implementation of this interface. One the other hand when I implement BoardRepostiry in Board class with annotation, error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the repo to:

```
public interface BoardRepository extends JpaRepository<Board,Long>{
//Methods here
}
```

And annotate the declaration:

```
@Autowired
private BoardRepository boardRepository;
```

And let Spring know where to look:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.repositories" />
```

(If BoardRepository was defined in com.repositories package)

Comment: After made that I have another error
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
I solved this by adding spring-beans to dependencies but then I have only 404 when I try run project on server.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't read this book, but it looks like spring data, 
[for example](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-jpa-data-hibernate-mysql/).
They also create interface without imtplementation.